# How to recover the deleted page in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have mistakenly deleted my Default.aspx page while deleting an image. Can some one help me please?

I haven't made any back-up and I don't know about version control.

Comment: Get it from SVN/VSS or use some undelete utility

Comment: can you tell me how to restore backup ?

Comment: you might find it in your recycle bin.. that's where mine always end up when delete locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that he doesn't use SVM. Undelete tool or typing in all the code again are your options. I'd suggest the latter. That's what i did and ever since i've remembered to alwys use version manager. :)

For future reference, you might want to install:

a) Mercurial, downloadable [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/)

b) VisualHG, downloadable [here](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/)

Since (b) probably is an extension, i don't think it will work with free versions of Visual Studio (that includes but is not limited to the Express versions). But there are free options as well, if you're prepared to do some work yourself and not have the version management be done automagically for you.

An other option you have is to go for:

c) Tortoise, downloadable [here](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/)

It will **NOT** integrate with VS but it will give you source version control, you won't have to install different tools, all the back-end advantages of Mercurial plus you get to see the **cutest turtle ever**.  And it's free.

Let me also quote @freefaller, who actually hinted about those stuff. I'm just helping him to put it on display so please feel free (obliged?) to give him thumbs-up (or rather the orange arrow up) so his reputation increases. After all, that's why we are here, not to help each other but to earn some reputation (first to a million goes to heaven for free, i've heard).

> Mercurial can be installed on it's own (but requires command line
>   interface to work). TortoiseHG can be installed which includes both
>   Mercurial and a nice Windows GUI interface (although command line
>   interface will still work, because Mercurial has been installed).
>   VisualHG can be installed if one the previous options has been
>   installed.

Comment: I am new to asp.net....i am working from last 2 weeks in a project...Mistakenly i have deleted the default page....So can you suggest me an easy method to restore that page.

Comment: I don't think there's a "point and click" way to do so. Frankly, as the other guys told you, you should get into habit of backuping (google Subversion and Tortoise for details). The fastest way in your case is probably to retype the whole thing. It can't be that much, if it's only been a few days. Harsh but good experience, i guess. Did you by any chance upload your project already? If it was a web site project, you can download the files. Maybe.

Comment: The Best way is to Restore that file from Recycle Bin....Simple and Awsome

Comment: Hmmm... Simple indeed, haha. Reminds me about the story of pen in space and the russian solution. Did you remove the file using Windows Explorer or through Visual Studio? I don't think my files go to the recycle bin when i remove them using VS... Also, the discussion was useful for you anyway in the long run.

Comment: I mistakenly deleted the file when i was using VS...I am using VS2010..Try it by simply making a dummy page and then delete it...See it goes to recycle bin  or not.... My files were in Recycle Bin :)

Comment: @user1535580 Well, i'll be darned! The dude is right... I stand corrected and congratulations to the simple solution. Nevertheless, i would still suggest that you look into the tools we've mentioned during the discussion. They ARE should-have's anyway. Ask any respectable pro. And in any case, you should mark at least one of the replies as an answer to your question and, possibly, grade them up, if you haven't done so yet.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a backup system in place (whether that is using [Windows Backup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore) or a version control system like Mercurial/[TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), SVN, Git, Visual SourceSafe, etc) then you're going to be out of luck.

It is possible that an "undelete" tool might find the file - but it really depends on how much you've done on the computer since the delete. There are plenty of utilities available on the web, both free and paid-for.

Unlike deleting files from Windows Explorer (which by default move files into the Recycle Bin) any file deleted by an application normally deletes the file on a permanent basis.

Computers can only "undo" things when the computer has something to "undo"... unfortunately it looks like you're in a situation where there is simply nothing the computer can do.

If you have already released a copy of the file to server, then you could get a copy of that - although it would not have any changes you have made since releasing it.

I would **strongly** recommend you look at using a version-control system (such as I mentioned earlier in my answer), and regularly back-up your code, for exactly this reason.

I have only ever used Visual SourceSafe and TortoiseHG, and I can thoroughly recommend [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) (and also [VisualHG plugin](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) for Visual Studio).

Comment: There's a Tortoise plug-in for VS? I thought we were stuck with the fantastic pleasures of checking in into TFS (which at our company probably is poorly configured because there's **always** an issue or two).

Comment: @Konrad, VisualHG will automatically show the status of files in the solution explorer, allows commit, history, difference features - and refreshes pretty quickly to reflect the most recent changes. One of those "once you have it, you can't live without it"

Comment: Ah, you're talking about Visual SourceSafe. Now, with risk that i'm being totally unupdated, my recollection of VSS can be summarized with the first quote [here](http://www.wadhome.org/svn_vs_vss.html). Of course, i'm not a fanatatic, so if you'll tell me that it's got better, i'll be happy to give it a try. (After all, .NET folks like things that are "Visual Something", don't we?)

Comment: Sorry @Konrad, I've obviously not been clear - I'm certainly **not** talking about Visual SourceSafe.  VisualHG is a plugin for **Mercurial**, and therefore also works with TortoiseHG. After many years of being forced to use VSS, I hate it with a passion, and wish I'd found TortoiseHG a long time ago

Comment: Got it. Many share your passion (including me). I'll take a look at the VisualHG right away. Just for the conversation's sake - while VHG seems to be free (GNU), it's a bit limited in support for the newer Studios ["Compatible with MSVS 2005, MSVS 2008 and also MSVS 2010 RC"](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/). Not that i LIKE the atrocity called VS12 but VS10 (not RC but a real one) should be in that list. I mean, it's second half of 2012...

Comment: Remember @Konrad, you still need Mercurial running (and repositories created on your projects) for VisualHG to use... it doesn't just work on it's own

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14686/discussion-between-konrad-viltersten-and-freefaller)

Comment: @ all of You....I have restored my files from Recycle Bin...HUHU :)

Comment: @user1535580 - that's good news. Now put in place backup procedures and version controls before you actually do lose your work!!